# Bit shifting for >32 bit long

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, byte, bit, byte-shifting

I am trying to extract the first 49 bits from a 7 byte array. I approached this byte using masks and bit shifting as follows:

`long byteVal = ((decryptedVCW[6] & 0xff)&((decryptedVCW[6] & 0xff)<<7)) | ((decryptedVCW[5] & 0xff) << 8) | ((decryptedVCW[4] & 0xff) << 16) | ((decryptedVCW[3] & 0xff) << 24) | ((decryptedVCW[2] & 0xff) << 32) | ((decryptedVCW[1] & 0xff) << 40) | ((decryptedVCW[0] & 0xff) << 48);`

Where decryptedVCW is a 56 bit byte array.

The masking and bit shifting work as expected until the 32 bit shift '<<32'.

As an example, the hex for decryptedVCW is E865037A9C6424 of which in binary is:

11101000011001010000001101111010100111000110010000100100

When I perform the above shifting I get 7AFC6503 in binary:

1111010111111000110010100000011

Does anyone have any idea why the bit shifting falls apart at 32 upwards and how to go about solving this issue?

Many thanks 
Shiv

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type of `decryptedVCW[2] & 0xff` is `int`, since the first operand is `byte` and the second is an `int` literal.

When the first operand of the `<<` operator is `int`, you are shifting an `int`, so if the second operand is 32, you'll get `int` overflow.

You can cast the first operand of the `<<` operator to `long` :

```
(((long)(decryptedVCW[2] & 0xff)) << 32)
```

or you can force the first operand to be a `long` by using a `long` literal in the `&` operation, as suggested by @shmosel :

```
(decryptedVCW[2] & 0xFFL) << 32
```

Comment: Or you can do `0xFFL`

Comment: @shmosel true. I didn't think of that.

Comment: Great explanation and solution. Thanks alot!